# How to employ sed correctly to replace all the white spaces with hyphens in long filenames

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I've been experiencing a wee issue in attempting to rename a batch of files. I need to insert (retrospectively) hyphens between a string of words in a group of unrelated files.   I thought i would employ sed to replace the white spaces with hyphens and I arrived at this (please see below). Now this returns the correct result on the command-line, but, doesn't physically change the file name in the directory.

```
$ ls 'long long long filename.txt' | sed 's/\s/-/g'
```

output

```
long-long-long-filename.txt
```

Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: `for f in *.txt; do mv "$f" "${f//[[:space:]]/-}"; done`

Comment: You have to actually issue a command that changes the filename; you're listing the filenames and then modify strings. It's either `mv`, like in the comment above, or one of two flavours of the `rename` command, as in the linked question.